# Jenkins PR and merge flow

Tags: github, jenkins, continuous-integration

We have a pretty standard CI flow in our company. The product is a multi-service application deployed in Kubernetes.
Each service's code is hosted in its own git repository. Developers issue PRs to `main`, and then a Jenkins job is triggered that builds the service and tests it, and pack it in a Docker image.

Once merged to `main`, we want to run another Jenkins job, which takes the previously built image and push it to ECR, as well as some other stuff.

The question is, how in the merge job can we relate to the previously built image? Of course, we don't want to be forced to build it again.

Currently what we're doing is as such: in the PR job, we tag the commit with the PR number+ the build number, and push the image to Artifactory with this value as the tag. Then, in the merge job, we read the tag for the current commit, and by that we know how to relate to the correct image.

The problem with that is that we cannot do a squash merge, because that creates a new commit and we cannot read the tag as we currently do.

Our use case sounds pretty standard, can someone share how it's done in your place?

Comment: Is the second Jenkins job a downstream job to the first one?

Comment: No, it's a job that is triggered once the user completes the merge

Comment: You could perhaps use the [EnvInject plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/) with the PR ID as the key and the information that needs to be passed to the second job as the value?

Comment: For this: "Developers issue PRs to main, and then a Jenkins job is triggered that builds the service and tests *it*, and pack it in a Docker image." Do you verify that the branch is fully up to date with `main` at that point? If no, then after the merge, there is no guarantee that `main` is the same as what you built.

Comment: Regarding this: "The problem with that is that we cannot do a squash merge"... why is that a problem? Why not just do a regular merge?